# Shorthand jQuery to focus first input in form in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I'm trying to do**

On the user click, I wish to focus on the first `input` in the (only) form inside the child `div` with the class `detailEdit`.

The jQuery code I have works - but it seems like a fairly long way round. Is there a shorthand version?

**My Code**

*HTML/PHP*

```
<div class="detailEdit">
    <form id="frm_contact">
        <span>Office:</span><br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company Telephone" id="frm_tel2" name="tel2" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $userData['tel1']; ?>" />
        <span>Mobile:</span><br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="frm_tel1" name="tel1" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $userData['tel2']; ?>" />                         
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
   $(this).children('div.detailEdit').first().children('form').first().children('input').first().focus();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$('.detailEdit').find('input:first').focus();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - I adapted it but it works perfectly: `$(this).find('.detailEdit').find('input:first').focus();`

Comment: I was glad that I can help. There is endless ways to do that in jQuery. ;)

Comment: sometimes focus is not enough to put the cursor in input fields so add: $('.detailEdit').find('input:first').select();

Answer (score 1):

You have input id, why not use it

```
$('#frm_tel2').focus();
```

you can also use

```
$('.detailEdit input:first').focus();
```

Comment: I have many forms on the page, each inside a div with a clickable element that will toggle the form's visibility. The `id` of the form and its inputs are all different but I'm after a function that can apply to each form. That would work if I only wanted the one to focus!

Comment: Based on the OP's HTML markup and given informations, this is the shortest solution, clever ;) I will give you +1, OP didn't mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović  It's shortest but not applicable in this situation. BTW I see that you're from Serbia, me too ;)

Comment: We didn't knew the whole situation until he wrote comment. Based on the text of the question, this is just fine solution.

Comment: LOL, Srbija okupirala SO :D

Comment: @MiljanPuzović hahaha...yeah ;) I see now that you're from Belgrade, contact me on FB if you're for some collaboration sometimes, you have info on my SO profile.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#frm_contact').find('input:first').focus();
```

or this if you don't want to use id of the form:

```
$('.detailEdit').find('form').find('input:first').focus();
```